# Restore an individual sharepoint site

Tags: 2007, backup

We're using Sharepoint 2007 (MOSS). One of our users has deleted a subsite and wants it back - is there any way to restore an individual Sharepoint site from a site collection backup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the past, what I've done is restore the backup to a spearate site collection via stsadm.  Then from that backup, I export the subsite.  I then import that into the original site collection.  Check out the [STSADM commands](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263384%28office.12%29.aspx), ther are a lot of switches for export.

Some 3rd party tools make recovery a lot easier like things from Docave, Quest and the like, but come at a premium.

Comment: +1 You beat me to it. restore, export subsite, and then import back to PROD.

Comment: I use DocAve at this client and it makes this type of operation extremely simple.  Just select the item to restore and restore it.  It takes about two minutes for the whole process and most of that time is just navigating to the item to be restored.

Comment: Yep, the products are great, costly when not utilized but invaluable when needed.