# Make a copy of sharepoint site under a new name

Tags: site-template, site, object-model

Since we can't save SharePoint site (with publishing feature enabled) as Template, I'm looking for a way to do this programmatically :

> Make a copy of "SiteA" with a new name
>   "SiteB" under the same SiteCollection

http://SPServer/Collection/SiteA

http://SPServer/Collection/SiteB

Comment: Related question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12300/restore-an-individual-sharepoint-site

Comment: @kit-menke Programmatically solution please "SharePoint object model"

Comment: @markov00 - you can call stsadm extensions r powershell whatetever programatically. Whats you're aversion to doing this?

Comment: @Ryan any exemple please ?!

Comment: How about "How can I run another application or batch file from my c# code"? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/06/01/146375.aspx

Comment: Or another great onen from .net perls - http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start

Comment: @Ryan for web application i have to change the application pool identity to some administrative account ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to do an export followed by an import. That should work without the duplicate GUID problem. PowerShell cmdlets are Export-SPWeb and Import-SPWeb.

Programmatically, there are equivalents to these in the Content Migration API (sometimes known as "PRIME"). These are in the [Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.deployment.aspx). You use the [SPExport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.deployment.spexport.aspx) class to export a content migration package, and then [SPImport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.deployment.spimport.aspx) to do the import.

There is an overview of content migration on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms453426.aspx). Don't forget that you can also use the web services API, as a programmatic alternative to the object model.

Comment: Or simply use the `export` and `import` STSADM commands: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262759%28office.12%29.aspx

Comment: @SPDoctor Yes i allready try this way but i cant get what i need. if siteB existe i get http://SPServer/Collection/SiteB/SiteA if i provide the rootURL http://SPServer/Collection/ the new site is not created.

Comment: @kit-menke Programmatically solution please "SharePoint object model"

Comment: SPDoctors answer should be marked as the answer based on your original question of making a copy SiteA to SiteB. In your original URLs Export/Import will work fine. In your response you say "if siteB exist[e] i get SPServer/Collection/SiteB/SiteA". If you did the export/import you would not get this. Please provide the exact PS command you're using.

Comment: @Bil-Simer i was talking about import/export using object model not PS command.

Comment: I have beefed up the response to reference the APIs.

Answer (score 1):

The Rayn's solution (see post comments) gived me an idea to run PowerShell Cmdlt from my code using :

System.Management.Automation

```
Collection<String> results = PowerShell.Create().AddScript(Ps).Invoke<String>();
```

but i still have a problem:

running this cmd "Get-Process" : i got the result.

running this cmd "Import-SPWeb -Identity http://SPserver/CollA/SiteA -Path c:\bkp\file.cmp" :

`The term 'Import-SPWeb' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

running the second cmd on powershell window cause no problem and i got my site imported.

**Solution :**

```
string BkpFile = @"C:\File.cmp";
string Url = "http://SPServer/CollA/SiteA";
string PsImport = "Import-SPWeb –Identity " + Url + " -Path " + BkpFile;
string PsPssnaping = "Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell";

PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();

ps.AddScript(PsPssnaping);
ps.AddScript(PsImport);
ps.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there no possibility to Duplicate a present working site to with another name ?
The reason being i would like to make changes to our Prod site and would like to test the changes on a test site for which i would need to replicate our prod site ..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason Microsoft has restricted this and they are not clear about it, I faced the same issue and found that

-> Its a Object Cache issue as it uses same GUIDS

One workaround to make a copy in the same webapp is to restore the site collection into different content DBs ( like make the current content DB offline , add a new content DB and restore) , I have not tested this properly but I think the Object cache issues will be there.